# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lat'

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, module, attributeerror

apispy_m.py

```
def aspy_geolocate(api_spy_akey, api_spy_ytvid):
    function_name = "geolocate"
    function_description = """Get location of a youtube video!"""
    if api_spy_akey == "":
        errcode = 001
        aspy_errhandler(function_name, errcode)
    else:
        pass
    r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=recordingDetails&id=%s&key=%s'%(api_spy_ytvid, api_spy_akey))
    api_spy_jsondata = json.loads(r.text)
    try:
        lat = api_spy_jsondata['items'][0]['recordingDetails']['location']['latitude']
        lon = api_spy_jsondata['items'][0]['recordingDetails']['location']['longitude']
        alt = api_spy_jsondata['items'][0]['recordingDetails']['location']['altitude']
    except KeyError:
        lat = "N/A"
        lon = "N/A"
        alt = "M/A"
```

moduletest.py

```
import apispy_m
api_spy_akey = "*Super secret api key ;)*"
api_spy_ytvid = "*youtube vid id*"
aspy = apispy_m
aspy.aspy_geolocate(api_spy_akey, api_spy_ytvid)
print aspy.lat
print aspy.lon
print aspy.alt
```

Error after running testmodule.py(Using Python2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print aspy.lat
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lat'
```

I can't seem to resolve this error. I have already tried `from apispy_m import *` and `from apispy_m import aspy_geolocate`. This is my first time creating a python module.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `lat` is a local variable. Have your function *return* those values (as a tuple) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set *local variables* in the function, not module attributes (globals). Local variables are not visible to anyone outside of the function (they seize to exist when the function exits).

You want to return those values instead:

```
try:
    lat = api_spy_jsondata['items'][0]['recordingDetails']['location']['latitude']
    lon = api_spy_jsondata['items'][0]['recordingDetails']['location']['longitude']
    alt = api_spy_jsondata['items'][0]['recordingDetails']['location']['altitude']
    return (lat, lon, alt)
except KeyError:
    return ("N/A", "N/A", "N/A")
```

(assuming you want to return `"N/A"` if *any* of the 3 componets are missing).

Then assign those 3 values to three new variables in the code that calls the function:

```
lat, lon, alt = aspy.aspy_geolocate(api_spy_akey, api_spy_ytvid)
print lat
print lon
print alt
```

Comment: @ACiDRAiN: Did you *replace* the `print` calls in your code with mine or did you leave those in?